# How can I use a reg ex to grab the super-domain?

Tags: javascript, regex

as opposed to the sub-domain.

I tried.

```
  var a = window.location.hostname.match(/(www.)?([^\.]*)\./)[2];
```

but this will grab

```
frozen-dusk-2587
```

from

```
https://frozen-dusk-2587.herokuapp.com/
```

and I just want

```
herokuapp
```

also I want it to work if there is multiple sub domains and just grab the last...for example

```
x.x.x.y.com
```

will always grab

```
y
```

Comment: Split the hostname on `.`, giving an array, then get the second-to-last element of the array.

Comment: Right, `hostname.split(".")` gives an array of the pieces of the hostname.

Comment: `var a = window.location.hostname,
          b = a.split('.'),
          c = b[b.length-2];` ... this works just tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = window.location.hostname.match(/(?:\.|^)([^\.]+)\.(?:[^\.]+)$/)[1];
```

This only matches the last two parts of the hostname, and only captures the second to last.

```
(?:\.|^)   -- (?: ... ) is a non-capture group (eg. not kept in your match)
           -- \.|^  matches a dot or the start of the string
([^\.]+)   -- capture  all characters that are not a dot
\.         -- matches a dot
(?:[^\.]+) -- non-capture - "all characters that are not dots"
$          -- match end of string
```

Without regular expressions you can do the following (as per @cade-galt 's comment suggested by @Pointy):

`var a = window.location.hostname, b = a.split('.'), c = b[b.length-2];`

Comment: @cadegalt The regular expression method appears to be slightly faster by about `44 ms` over 100,000 iterations of both methods.

Comment: @WillS - did you run a jsperf of something ?

Comment: @cadegalt I just used `console.time()`. I get 34%±0.92% slower [using jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/hostname/2) on Chrome.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if you have a domain like `example.co.uk`, this will capture "co" rather than "example".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single line solution :

```
location.hostname.replace("."+location.hostname.split(".").pop(), "").split(".").pop()
```